# Guidance for when to moderator flag vs raise many standard flags

Tags: support, declined-flags

I've a feeling that this kind of comes down to individual mods' preferences, but I'm hoping maybe there's some standard guidance that I've missed.

I encountered a question today which had a vast block of code, and long explanation with it. Following the question was a request for clarification from someone else, followed by several further comments from the OP - something of a stream of consciousness, detailing other things he'd discovered.

Then there were two 'answers' to that question also from the OP, both of which just included further detail. Finally, the OP had left a comment on the last 'answer' stating that the problem was resolved, and linking to another (much more concise) question he'd asked that dealt with the actual problem. There were no other answers or comments, and no votes.

I flagged one of the answers as NAA before realising how bad the rest of it was, so followed it up with a moderator flag saying:

> This whole question and its two answers are just a stream-of-consciousness from the OP, with a final comment at the end linking to a different question which appears to contain the answer - I haven't read through all of this question, but it seems like it's almost certainly redundant.

That was declined with the response:

> declined - Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags: see What is Flagging?".

But I'm not sure what standard flag I should have used - would two 'NAA' flags, a bunch of no-longer-needed flags, plus a close vote have been better? It seems like that's more work for mods plus a high chance of the close vote ageing away, which is obviously a worse outcome for the site than a moderator just deleting the whole thing.

The two answers have now been deleted and the question closed as a dupe of the one linked in OP's final comment, by a moderator - presumably the same one who declined my flag - so it seems that he agreed with my analysis. What could I have done better?

Comment: If you're dealing with multiple problems and wondering what the best action is, do know [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers)  has enough regulars around to either advice or help with the moderation of such train-wrecks. We do have a rather lengthy [FAQ](https://socvr.org/faq), sorry about that.

Answer (score 8):

> almost certainly redundant

This isn't something a diamond mod needs to handle. "Redundant" is a duplicate question. Duplicates can be handled by the community without our involvement.

Other things that don't need our involvement:

- Closing a low quality question
- Closing a question in general
- Fixing bad links
- Anything else you, as a user, can issue a standard flag for.

---

All of this said, a moderator flag for a user posting a duplicate question repeatedly is a valid use of the mod flag. That usually indicates someone at the very least needs to be educated in how to post a question (ie. don't post the same question) to a user evading a temporary suspension with another account.

Comment: These were answers, no questions, I believe. As in many self-answers to the same question.

Comment: OK, so, to clarify, it's better for me to raise 3 'not an answer' flags, 5 'no longer needed' comment flags and vote to close a question, than to raise a single mod flag? I guess that's fine if it's the case, but I'm sure I've seen advice elsewhere that mods prefer one mod flag over many 'no longer needed' comment flags.

Comment: @yivi - yes, that's correct, 1 question, 3 answers to that question. Sorry, I've made that clearer in my question now.

Comment: No, "This whole question" - Deal with that problem. Close the question as a duplicate. If it's low quality, downvote it. The community can deal with closed questions and delete them if they are that bad. You need one flag.

Comment: OK, that's a fair comment. I guess I'm not convinced it would have got closed though. For reference here's the question (and the dupe): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48209274/spark-job-hangs-crashes-after-several-hours. I know that if I'd encountered that in the Close Votes review queue, I'd almost certainly have skipped - especially if I'd missed the one comment at the bottom of 3 long posts that made the duplication clear. Hence my feeling that a close vote would just age away.

Comment: I realise, of course, that it causes me no harm whatsoever if it doesn't get closed - I'd most likely have already forgotten about it had I done that - but it doesn't feel like the best result for SO.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave If a post doesn’t receive many views, does it matter if it gets closed properly or not? Don’t worry about the tumbleweeds, worry about the popular posts instead :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters - fair enough, and that's kind of what I'm saying in my last comment above. But I wasn't really asking about this specific post, more general guidance and I'm left more confused than I was. A moderator deleted the non-answers and closed the question as a dupe, but Andy's advice here seems to be that I should just do a close vote, which would leave the answers - i.e. not what the moderator actually did, but then the moderator declined my flag, which I take to mean I did something wrong, even though he did what I think I asked for.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, and I'm not completely sure I agree with the principle behind your point - isn't it like the broken window principle? If we don't look after the many low-view posts to the best of our ability, then aren't they all setting precedents for low quality rubbish that creeps into the popular ones?

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave I was that moderator. I declined the flag for exactly the reasons Andy states here. But while I was there I also closed the post, as it was still a duplicate. That’s what I hoped the community would have done in that case.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave At any rate, community moderation is never perfect and 100% done, you as an individual community member can do your best to contribute your bit but you shouldn’t worry too much if one or two low-traffic posts escape closing even after you voted or flagged; that way madness lies. And us elected moderators have enough on our hands without also picking up the jobs the community can do.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I'm not disagreeing, I completely understand your point, but am trying to understand what the right thing to do next time would be, as your 'decline' tells me I did something wrong. The result I was hoping for was 2 answers deleted, 1 question closed and that's what you did. That was done as the result of a single mod flag. It might also have been achieved with 2 NAA flags and a close vote. Is that what I should have done? I've previously read that a single flag (for comments) is better than many. Is there something inherently different about comments?

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave: You need to have used NAA flags and a close vote, as *those are mostly handled by the community*. Otherwise, you end up accumulating declined flags and become flag banned for a while. Elected moderators can't handle all the work that the community can do instead, we'd need many, many more moderators. Just because I cleaned up *this case* doesn't mean I can handle *every* case.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - understood, thank you. I didn't realise that NAA flags are also handled by the community - I assumed that they always end up with a mod. Presumably the difference with comments is that they are always handled by a mod? So, one mod flag for many comments is better than many flags, because either way they will be handled by a mod, right?

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave: for the most part, yes. Comments that acquire enough flags are auto-deleted (how many flags depend on the comment content), and flag handling for multiple comments on the same post is streamlined. If you see 4, 5 or more comments in a row that need flagging, a single custom flag becomes more efficient.